# How to add a space every time X appears?

Tags: python, list, addition, space

For example, how do I make this:

`file1.exefile2.exefile3.exe`

Into this:

`file1.exe file2.exe file3.exe`

In this example ".exe" is X.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a place that makes your homework. You have to show what you've tried so far before we can help you.

Comment: I've tried to replace ".exe" with ".exe ". Hasn't worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can first split the given text on `x` i.e. `.exe` in this case, then join all the split items by x + , and finally strip off on the space to get the desired result.

```py
text='file1.exefile2.exefile3.exe'
x = '.exe'
f'{x} '.join(text.split(x)).strip()

#output: 'file1.exe file2.exe file3.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
text = ".exe ".join(text.split(".exe")).rstrip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a RegEx:

```
import re
string = 'file1.exefile2.exefile3.exe'
print(re.sub('\.exe(?!$)', '.exe ', string))
```

The first argument is the RegEx to match, the second is the replacement and the third is the string.

The `\.` inside the RegEx just means a dot (".") and the `(?!$)` is a negative lookahead onto the end of the string. This way the last ".exe" is not matched. Plainly, it checks whether the next symbol is the end of the string and if it is, the pattern does not match.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (if you want to do this manually)

```
string="file1.exefile2.exefile3.exe"
X="exe"
lenX=len(X)
temp=""
start=0
for i in range(string.count(X)):
   string=string[start:]
   if(X in string):
     temp+=string[:string.index(X)+lenX]+" "
     start=string.index(X)+lenX
print(temp.strip())
```